# A word for listing out objects in a list

Tags: single-word-requests

So when listing out two things, it is appropriate to use "both".

What about for lists of more than two? Does "all" work?

Ex. He ordered both a steak and a side.

vs. He ordered ___ a steak, a side, and some wine. (or further items, as required)

Comment: You don't need "both" in your fist option and you don't need anything in the blank in your second option.

Comment: @ed86 You need something before or after fish and chips if you ordered two separate dishes, one of which has fish and the other has chips. Fish and chips is one dish. Look at the second example. It is clear that it is not one dish in the OP's context.

Comment: @Rathony If they're two separate dishes and fish and chips are also on the menu, then _he ordered the fish and the chips_.

Comment: @Rathony *aren't also on. lol way to take advantage of a typo.

Comment: I've edited to make it more clear what exactly I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some possibilities:

> - He ordered the entire list.
> - He ordered all of them.
> - He ordered everything on the list.
> - He ordered half the menu (the entire menu).

Enjoy!

Comment: I need a word that can be placed directly in the format that I have in the question, i.e. He ordered ___ fish, chips, and a drink.